# Eclipse and println seem to disagree on value of dynamically-set private final static field

Tags: java, eclipse, static, final, introspection

While playing with introspection, I found an interesting situation where:

- Eclipse's debugger tooltip displays `true`
- println prints `false` (note the output in the Console tab):

[image: eclipse]

I am trying to set the value of the `private final static` field, I guess I did it wrong?
What is actually happening here?

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Main {

    private final static boolean VAR = false; // I want to dynamically set this to true

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field field = Main.class.getDeclaredField("VAR");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(null, true);
        System.out.println(VAR);
    }
}
```

Comment: since VAR is a constant it could have been inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is 'inlining' the `static final` value. If you look at the bytecode for the `println` you will see something like:

```
iconst_0
invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(boolean)
```

Because it knows the value won't change the compiler has generated code which is loading the value 0 (for false) directly without referring to the `VAR` variable so your change to the variable is ignored.

Because of the inlining you can't rely on being able to change the value of a `static final` variable with reflection.